# Can I access Hudson's plugin proxy settings from within a plugin?

Tags: java, proxy, hudson, hudson-plugins

So, I have Hudson setup locally, and I am using an open source plugin that lets me create AWS Stacks from CloudFormation using the AWS SDK.  However, the plugin fails because I am on a VPN, and I need to go through a proxy server.  I have configured Hudson to use my proxy server for downloading (and updating) plugins.  My question is - is there any way for my plugin to access Hudson's proxy settings and re-use those so that I don't have to enter the proxy settings in the plugin as well?  I checked to see if Hudson happened to be setting the http.proxyHost, etc, System properties, and it doesn't appear that it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading the Hudson code and looking at how it uses the proxy settings, I was able to utilize those in my plugin with the following lines:

```
    Hudson hudson = Hudson.getInstance(); 
    ProxyConfiguration proxyConfig = hudson != null ? hudson.proxy : null;
```

From there, I can call proxyConfig.name, proxyConfig.port, proxyConfig.getUserName(), and proxyConfig.getPassword() to get the settings that I needed.